# python raw socket: Protocol not supported

Tags: python, linux, sockets

I am trying to open a raw socket with Python under linux.

My simple code:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_IP)
s.bind((HOST, 5454))
```

And I got this error:

```
[ERROR] Protocol not supported
```

By the way, I am using python 2.7.3 under linux 12.04, and I used root to run the code.

Does anyone have a clue?

**Update**: [The solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19732282/8414561) given by [dstromberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1084684/dstromberg) is correct. If you want the whole packet, then use his solution. However, there is another combination:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_TCP)
```

that also works.

In this case, you will receive a whole TCP packet with IP and TCP headers on it.
If your use [dstromberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1084684/dstromberg)'s solution, you will also see the ethernet header. So it depends on how 'raw' you want your packet to be.

Comment: FYI I get the same error when running it as root.

Comment: Try `AF_UNIX`, instead of `AF_INET`.

Comment: @Anthony, It seems work. I got new error, though. Let me do some test and see whether it works. Thanks for advice~~~

Comment: Are you trying to receive all IP packets? All packets? Or all packets of a specific IP protocol?

Comment: @Robᵩ,All Packets. We have conversation in another post. And this is the way for me to bypass the TCP part. If I can receive all the packet then I can acheive the goal: one socket send, one socket receive.

Comment: One reason you may receive this error is that [Raw TCP packets are prohibited by Windows Desktop machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62281097/why-am-i-getting-an-exception-on-windows-8-using-raw-sockets-with-ipproto-tcp). Apparently Windows 10 for the cloud may allow them...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try socket.AF_PACKET instead of socket.AF_INET.

Comment: I tried, and I got "[ERROR] No such device". It confused me, actually.

Comment: @JerryMeng - What OS are you running on? On Ubuntu 12.04, with root privileges, `socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW)` worked for me.

Comment: @Robᵩ then how do you bind your socket to a host? like s.bind((HOST, 5454))? I got  "[ERROR] No such device". And by the way, If I use AF_PACKET, why I don't need to specify the proto argument?

Comment: @JerryMeng 1) You don't bind raw sockets to hosts. You are bypassing IP, so you don't get any of its features. 2) I  didn't specify a protocol because you said "All Packets".

Comment: @JerryMeng - You can bind raw sockets to a specific device & protocol. So, you might try `s.bind(("eth0", 0x0800))`.

Comment: @Robᵩ That is what I was typing...Yes, I think I still need to bind to something.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40392/discussion-between-jerry-meng-and-rob)

Comment: @Robᵩ I think I realize the point you were talking about. Let me do some test. thanks man~~~

Comment: Why does this work? It's not even listed in [the py2 documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html).

Answer (score 0):

This runs without error as root:

```
#!/usr/local/cpython-3.3/bin/python

import socket as socket_mod

#s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_IP)
socket = socket_mod.socket(socket_mod.AF_PACKET, socket_mod.SOCK_RAW, socket_mod.IPPROTO_IP)
#socket.bind(('localhost', 5454))
socket.bind(('lo', 5454))
```

Comment: In fact, I have figured it out. And the second line is not right. 5454 won't give your error, neither any packet. 0x0800 is the correct port to use. Thanks for answering~~

Comment: Why two answers? Wouldn't it be clearer to merge this into your first answer?

Answer (score -2):

Try socket.AF_UNIX, it can solve your problem, good luck.