# Why am I getting an exception on Windows 8 using raw sockets with IPPROTO_TCP?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, packet-sniffers, raw-sockets

I was playing with raw sockets on my Windows 8 machine. I created a socket as follows:

```
s=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_RAW,IPPROTO_TCP)
s.bind((gethostname(),0)) s.ioctl(SIO_RCVALL,RCVALL_ON)
```

But on binding line python is throwing an exception as follows

```
OSError: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied
```

But with `IPPROTO_UDP` as the third argument, it's working fine.

I also have an AWS machine running Windows 10, on which it's working fine with same third argument (IPPROTO_TCP)

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: [Same question for C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72834234/how-to-send-tcp-packets-using-raw-sockets-in-winsock). Same answer. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Found the reason from Microsoft documentation...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/tcp-ip-raw-sockets-2

> TCP data cannot be sent over raw sockets.